# Getting RTC stream name from Project explorer or Navigator

Tags: eclipse, rtc

Is there any API or way in which we can get the RTC stream name from the Project explorer or Navigator view selection in eclipse.
I am creating a RTC util which needs some basic inputs like stream name or project (that user select on navigator), which in turn communicates with RTC in doing our project related activies.

Project explorer / Navigator shows the users local repository name, but i am unable go get those, these two views provide the file as IFile or IResource(IFolder, IProject.. etc) or ICompliationUnits.
which gives only the path of the file.

So Is there anyway where i can get those stream name from those project/file that user select.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found with little exploration. here it goes.
Once the Project (created) or loaded throught RTC, 
Projects get the additionals details added to its lable, like RTC component and Respository they came from.

Since the Project explorer view  is a tree viewer, cast the selection to TreeSelection and using the getText() method, get the complete display name of that tree item. 
Which by parsing gives the user repository name.
Using that as a repository name, query the RTC for user "WORKSPACE" and get the user repository connection and get its flow target (both delivery and accept), which is mostly where there user repository created from.

And this solves my probelm as i want only the current delivery flowtarget (no matter where the user repository created from).

get the source repository of the